# In IntelliJ IDEA, how do I disable the auto-format on simple methods

Tags: java, intellij-idea, formatting, ide

After making simple methods such as:

```
    public int getWidth() {
        return game.getWidth();
    }

    public int getHeight() {
        return game.getHeight();
    }

    public Game getGame() {
        return game;
    }
```

It will be reformatted as:

```
 public int getWidth() { return game.getWidth();}

    public int getHeight() { return game.getHeight();}

    public Game getGame() { return game;}
```

In the settings under Editor >> Code Style >> Java >> Keep when reformatting,
I have the box for "simple methods in one line" unchecked and it still happens. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just saying, it's not that bad since you can click on the method and it expands it.

But you can click File | Settings | Editor | General | Code Folding and click Collapse by Default. Then uncheck One-Line Methods under the Java section.